# html многоуровневые списки

Tags: html

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в многоуровневом списке горизонтально поменять положение элементов `<li>` (извините за странную формулировку вопроса)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li ul{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Вы об этом?

Comment: спасибо:) как де я сам не догадался))) (надо было подвинуть влево фторой уровень списка ато невлазил в таблицу)

Comment: список-меню "работает" на jquery, при нажатии на первий уровень открывается второй, а после применения стиля при откритии второго уровня маркери пунктов стали появлятся с задержкой:( , убирай стиль - все норм...

Comment: решыл убрать маркер вопще) чтоб не мешал